# How can I update a configuration in a Flink transformation?

Tags: java, configuration, apache-flink, flink-streaming, distributed-system

Given a Flink streaming job which applies a `map()` operation to the stream.

This `map()` operation reads its configuration from some properties, and maps data accordingly. For example, the configuration specifies to read attribute "input", and write it using a different attribute name "output" to the stream. This already works fine.

Now the configuration changes, for example the transformation is to use a different attribute name for the output.

Therefore I am looking for a way to let all Flink tasks reread a new configuration at run-time.

Is there a possibility

- to suspend a `KafkaSource`
- wait until the pipeline has drained (flush)
- trigger all tasks in the cluster to reread a configuration file (coordinated)
- resume the `KafkaSource`

programmatically in Flink without redeployment?

In case it matters

- I am currently using Flink 1.14, but we have to migrate to 1.15 soon.
- The job uses checkpoints.
- The job uses `KafkaSource`, `JdbcSink`, `KafkaSink` as provided by Flink.
- There are additional custom sinks for JDBC and InfluxDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would broadcast your configuration stream changes, which means they would be sent to every instance of the operator that is doing the attribute transformation. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/ for an example of applying a Rule to a stream of Shapes, which seems to mimic some of your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, this is done by reading config changes in a `Stream`, and then using `connect` operation. This way You can handle mapping of You data stream using `map1` function and then if any change in config is detected it can be handled in `map2` and stored in state and You can make `map1` function depend on the last received config change.

Not sure if that solves Your issue but seems it should work just fine.

Comment: In some cases it may be more appropriate to broadcast the configuration stream.